# Get image url from MacroPartialView Umbraco 8

Tags: umbraco, umbraco8

Hi I used to be able to get image url from macro with:

```
var imgMain = Model.MacroParameters["image"];
    int imgWidth = Convert.ToInt32(Model.MacroParameters["imageWidth"]);
    var mediaItemOne = Umbraco.TypedMedia(imgMain);
    <img src='@mediaItemOne.Url.GetCropUrl(width:imageWidth)' alt=''/ >
```

What is the new way in Umbraco 8 as I get the following error now and I cannot find any documentation on how to do it:

> UmbracoHelper' does not contain a definition for 'TypedMedia' and no
>   accessible extension method 'TypedMedia' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'UmbracoHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive
>   or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `Umbraco.TypedMedia`, just use `Umbraco.Media` the APIs have been simplified as dynamics are no longer supported and the former method is no longer necessary.

The same goes for Content - `TypedContent` has gone away, and now `Umbraco.Content` returns a strongly typed IPublishedContent item.

Answer (score 1):

OK, if anyone comes across this post, this is how I finally got it to work in Umbraco 8

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Macros.PartialViewMacroPage
@using Umbraco.Web;
@using Umbraco.Web.Composing
@{
    var img         = Model.MacroParameters["image"].ToString();
    int imageWidth  = Convert.ToInt32(Model.MacroParameters["imageWidth"]);
    var udi         = Udi.Parse(img);
    var imgUrl      = Current.UmbracoHelper.ContentQuery.Media(udi).Url;

    <img src='@imgUrl.GetCropUrl(width:imageWidth)' alt='' />
}
```

Comment: Note that Current.UmbracoHelper is exactly the same as using the Umbraco property - you can use `Umbraco.Media` now... see my answer below as well.  Guidance from Umbraco HQ is that the `Current` static (or Singleton as it's known) object should never be used, and in most cases, you already have everything you need to access content, media and more.

Comment: @RobertFoster Im using something similar but I cant get it to work. Im getting the below error on Umbraco.Media :- System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentExtensions.Url(IPublishedContent content, String culture, UrlMode mode) in D:\a\1\s\src\Umbraco.Web\PublishedContentExtensions.cs:line 1436
   at ASP._Page_Views_MacroPartials_Animations_ImageWithTextAnimationMacro_cshtml.Execute()

Comment: @Debasish it would help to see an example of the code - perhaps you need to create a new question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage

@{
    var site = Model.Root();
    var bannerImage = Model.Value<IPublishedContent>("bannerImage");

}

<img scr="@bannerImage.Url" />
```